# Which plugins are run with maven package

Tags: maven, maven-3

When I execute `mvn package` a bunch of tasks are run which I didn't explicitly specify.

How can I change that, or see which plugins will be run

Comment: What kind of plugin are you trying to change and most important why are you trying to change it?

Comment: I don't think it has relevance. I just want to see them. But just for the sake of answering the question: My parent POM a stork task to build a jar. I want to skip this task because it fails for JDK10, in favor of a different component  that generates a docker image..

Comment: If you think so...a parent pom should never have code nor running plugins in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is deigned this way, it will automatically run all the preceding life-cycle phases in order to complete the goal.

A neat way to see your whole build and the phases in which each plugin goal is executed is to run: `mvn fr.jcgay.maven.plugins:buildplan-maven-plugin:1.3:list`

You can trigger an individual plugin goal by naming the plugin explicitly and calling the goal after it (like buildplan above), you can even finalize with an `@my-execution-id` to further refine it.

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the default maven build life cycle (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), you can see that 'mvn package' run all these phases sequentially:

- validate - validate the project is correct and all necessary
  information is available
- compile - compile the source code of the
  project
- test - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit
  testing framework. These tests should not require the code be
  packaged or deployed
- package - take the compiled code and package it
  in its distributable format, such as a JAR.

You can also look at the maven dependency scope (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). By default, dependencies use the 'compile' scope. For example, if a dependency is not required to compile your project but for execute any task for the tests, you can define it this way:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>group-a</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```